# The cubic function meets Number Theory

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

The cubic function$$
2^{k + 1} x^3  + 3x^2  - d = 0
$$where 
$$
d,k \in {\Bbb Z} ,d \gg 2^{k + 1} 
$$

the discriminant  $$
\Delta  < 0
$$
 so there is one real root and two imaginary roots.
My question is if the real root **can be a positive integer**.

Comment: $$
d \gg 2^{k + 1} 
$$
 was put there only to emphasize it must be large.About the elliptic curves, I thought the roots of this cubic function could be solved by classical methods as described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots

Comment: Yeah you're gonna have trouble using these formulas. Perhaps you should start with $k=0$ and try to find something. I tried expanding $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$ and see what kind of constraints you can put on $a,b,c$ and still obtain your equation above (when $k=0$ we can do that). For instance $a+b+c = 3$, so we reduce to two variables $a$ and $b$ by letting $c = a+b-3$. The other constraint gives you $ab + (a+b)(a+b-3) = 0$, a quadratic form in $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance,I didn't get how $$
2^{k + 1} x^3  + 3x^2  - d = 0
$$
is a elliptic curve? Could you please clarify

Comment: Oh god, this is so not an elliptic curve. Sorry I tend to imagine $y^2$'s when I see cubics. XD Would've edited my comment but it was too late, deleted it.

Comment: Unfortunately k is a variable and we can not solve for a specific case, so I guess we should use the root finding formulaes.

Comment: Believe me you don't want to use these to understand the equation in terms of integer solutions... the nested cubic roots and square roots are just a pain to work with.

Comment: @kurtul: Please clarify that you want to solve for $x$ if **both** $k$ and $d$ are **given**? Otherwise the answer is a clear YES: Given $k$ take a 'large' $x$, compute $d$ and you get what you want. I know this is cheating, but ...

Comment: We want to solve for x if both k and d are variables and see under which conditions of k and d the root can (or can not) be a positive integer. So I guess we have to deal with the cube root formula.

Comment: @Kurtul : Where did this problem come from? It feels very particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some cases you can rule out. For instance, if we re-write the equation as 
$$
x^2(2^{k+1} x + 3) = d,
$$
then if $d$ is square-free then you cannot have a solution, unless $x=1$ is a solution (and then you are welcome to check if it is, i.e. if $d = 2^{k+1}+3$, but I guess that is not gonna happen because $d \gg 2^{k+1}$). Another trick you can use is to read this equation mod $2^{k+1}$ : it reads 
$$
3x^2 \equiv d \pmod{2^{k+1}}.
$$
If $k$ is large this equation can rule out most of the cases, because you can write it as $x^2 \equiv d \cdot 3^{-1} \pmod{2^{k+1}}$ and it might be that $d 3^{-1}$ is not a square $\pmod{2^{k+1}}$.

A third option would be to read the equation $\pmod 3$ : 
$$
x^2 ( (-1)^{k+1} x ) = (-1)^{k+1} x^3 = d \pmod 3.
$$
Since $x^3 \equiv x \pmod 3$, your solution must satisfy $x = (-1)^{k+1} d \pmod 3$.

So these are a few checks you can make to rule out some particular values of $d$ and $k$.

As of the general case, I have no idea.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

After giving some thought I concluded that the cubic function$$
2^{k + 1} x^3  + 3x^2  - d = 0
$$where 
$$
d,k \in {\Bbb Z} ,d \gg 2^{k + 1} 
$$
and k,d are variables, determining if the real root **can be a positive integer** can only be done by using the long and painfull way using the classical methods as described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots.

Comment: I just wanted to be clear ; did you actually solve the problem using these formulas? Do you have an answer? I don't think so. If you are given particular values of $k$ and $d$, then the cubic roots approach is *probably the worst, by far*. For instance, if you are given square-free integer $d$ and some integer $k$, it is way faster to use my techniques than to compute the cubic roots. The techniques I described below can probably get rid of most cases.

Comment: Using the cubic roots formula, the best you can do is get a numerical approximation of the real solution, look at it, and then see if the closest integer to the numerical approximation is a real root. But then again, this is not a general technique, and at this point discussing which is better depends on why you want to solve this problem.

Comment: The aim is not to calculate, the aim is to see if the root can be a positive integer or not